# best way to merge 2 disparate data sets in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to merge 2 disparate data sets in javascript?  For example,

```
const parentRecords = [{
   id: 1,
   mycol1: 'parent name',
}]

const childRecords = [{
   childid: 2,
   parentId: 1,
   mycol2: 'child name',
}]

const mergedRecords = [...parentRecords, ...childRecords]
```

This code returns an array where each of the records above exist as separate rows.  I need the result to look like this:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   mycol1: 'parent name',
   childid: 2,
   parentId: 1,
   mycol2: 'child name',
}]
```

Comment: Items have to be merged together when a parent has the same `id` than a children `parentId`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify on which criteria items should be merged. In my answer I'm assuming it's based on the parent `id` and the children `parentId`:

```js
const parentRecords = [{
   id: 1,
   mycol1: 'parent name',
}];

const childRecords = [{
   childid: 2,
   parentId: 1,
   mycol2: 'child name',
}];

const result = parentRecords.map((x) =>
  Object.assign(
    x,
    childRecords.find((y) => y.parentId === x.id)
  )
);

console.log(result);
```